# How to extract a certain block of text from web site

Tags: extract

i have to extract useful information from web

i can i do using c#

example

title:   abc

i have get only "abc"

Comment: do you mean <title>abc</title> ?

Answer (score 1):

As, @Oded♦ recommended, [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) will be useful.

This is example of html agility pack.

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address @azeem's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract text from a website, you need to use an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM parser you can extract required elements. If you pre-aware of the block id or if you able to prepare it then the extraction is quite simple.